# Pull back a query based off an onChange using Ruby on Rails, jQuery and Ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Here is what I want to do:

1. Based on two dropdown values (:year, :category), retrieve a "select * from tablename 
   where year = :year and category = :category".
2. I want to do this from an $('#lookup_category').change() rather than a form submit.

Here is the jQuery code (lookup.js):

```
$('#lookup_category').change(function(){
     year = $('#lookup_year :selected').text()
     category = $('#lookup_category :selected').text()

     $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:'/lookup/getrows',
         data: 'year, category',    //// I dont know if this is correct
         datatype:  //// dont know what i want here yet, JSON maybe 
     })
});
```

Here is my getrows method in lookup controller:

```
def getrows
  @lookuprows = Lookup.return_lookup_row(params[:year], params[:category])
end
```

And here is my query from Lookup class:

```
def self.return_lookup_row
  Lookup.select("year, category, field, serialnumber, active, remarks").where("year =
               ? and category = ?", params[:year], params[:category]) 
end
```

Can you tell if I am going in the right direction?  And how would I return these query results to the same page.

Thanks

Comment: Using user inputs for database queries is always a great idea, makes the kids so happy ?

Comment: Even if they are from select options?

Comment: Does'nt matter what they are from, anyone can write anything into that ajax function, and those commands are tranferred directly to the server without sanitizing and checking and someone could delete your entire database with one line of code. Also your data should be something like -> `data: {year : year, category : category},`

Comment: How do i prevent anyone from writing into that ajax function?

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right way but there are some improvements that can be made:

1. Ensure that category and year is provided before firing an AJAX request
2. Remove the URL '/lookup/rows' from your javascript code, hardcoded URLs will cause problems when you change your routes.
3. Implement lookup requests as GET requests

I assume you have installed the jquery-rails gem, if not please do so and follow the instructions here: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Now there's a nifty feature in Rails UJS (unobtrusive javascript) that enables you to create a kind of javascript binding to your tags.

Let's modify a few lines in your view, in your form builder:

```
<%= f.select :year, ... your previous parameters ..., :'data-remote' => true, :'data-url' => '/lookup/getrows', :'data-type' => 'json' %>
<%= f.select :category, ... your previous parameters ..., :'data-remote' => true, :'data-url' =>  '/lookup/getrows', :'data-type' => 'json' %>
```

What does it mean?

data-remote: sets a flag on the HTML tag that the select box should be observed for changes
data-url: defines the URL where to look for the data (try to use url helpers if possible like lookup_getrows_path or similar) 
data-type: What data type the response will be

Now to your controller which should respond to JSON:

```
def getrows
  @lookuprows = Lookup.return_lookup_row(params[:year], params[:category]).all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @lookuprows }
  end
end
```

What's left is the javascript which turns out to be pretty simple:

```
// this handler will be invoked BEFORE the request is sent to the server, we can do checking here
$('#lookup_category, #lookup_year').live('ajax:before', function(evt) {
  var categorySelect = $('#lookup_category');
  var yearSelect = $('#lookup_category');

  // we need both values to send a request
  if(categorySelect.val() && yearSelect.val()) {
    // add parameters
    $(this).data('params', categorySelect.serialize() + '&' + yearSelect.serialize());
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
});

// this handler will be invoked when the request has completed successfully
$('#lookup_category, #lookup_year').live('ajax:success', function(evt, data) {
  // data is now an array containing your objects 
  // you can dump them on firebug or your web browser console using console.log(data); 
});
```

Comment: should this work even if i have :year in a collection_select and :category in a grouped_collection_select?

Comment: yes, as long as the output is a <select> tag it should work ;)

Comment: is there an example of how I can display the data in the success handler?

Comment: the controller should return a JSON object, you can inspect the "data" in the success handler by adding `console.log(data);` into the success handler. Then you will see the content of `data` in your browser's development console (firebug, IE developer tools,...). The contents of data can be accessed like any array/object in javascript. Displaying the data is up to you (most likely you will iterate through the data and create HTML tags like `$('<div/>').text(data['name']).appendTo($('body'));`)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work.  I put a console.log("XX") right before the 'var categorySelect' in the ajax:before call and that is not showing up in the firebug console. Here is what I have in my '<%= grouped_collection_select (:lookup, ...previous parameters..., :data_remote => true, :data_url => '/lookup/getrows', :data_type => 'json') %>'  I wanted to make sure I had the parameters in the grouped_collection_select correct.  I believe I have used your example correctly but the fact that the console.log does not show means something is wrong somewhere.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: hi, make sure the id to which you bind the ajax:before event is correct (I used #lookup_category as an example, inspect your html source code and check the ID on the select tag)

Comment: sled - since im appending the 'data-remote', 'data-url', and 'data-type' to the select tag, I no longer need the $ajax call in the $('#lookup_category').change(function() do i?  Also, in the 'data-url', it already knows to look in the lookup controller for the getrows method correct?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes, you don't need the $('#lookup_category').change(function()).. anymore, jquery-ujs (the rails javascript stuff) handles this stuff for you. `data-remote` marks the select box, so jquery-ujs knows that this select box wants to fetch data when the value changes. data-type tells jquery-ujs what we're expecting from the server (html, json, text) and data-url tells jquery-ujs where to look for this data. jquery-ujs makes a request to this url and submits the only value of the select box. When the data is received, jquery-ujs will call your javascript callback and you handle the data on your own

Comment: Do I need to edit anything in my routes.rb file for this to work?